# How to get the event that video has been started playing in webview in xamarin.forms

Tags: html, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin.forms app I am using a webview. I have a video control is playing video on the top.

I am using webview which also html5 based video. When someone playing the video I want to stop video that is playing on control.

How to do that in xamarin.forms.

Answer (score 1):

## in your html5 file

set the **id** of the video

```
<video id="video">...</video>
```

And add listener in JS

```
var video=document.getElementById("video");
video.addEventListener("play",function(){  
    
});
```

## Solution 1

If you want to stop play it ,why don't you stop it in Html 5?

```
var video=document.getElementById("video");
video.addEventListener("play",function(){  
    video.stop();
});
```

## Solution 2

If you do want to stop it in Forms , it will be a little complex.

You should implement it in `Custom Renderer`

```
var video=document.getElementById("video");
video.addEventListener("play",function(){  
    
  invokeNativeMethod();

});
```

The `invokeNativeMethod` JavaScript function is not defined in the web page, and will be injected into it by each custom renderer.

You can refer [HybridWebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview) for more details about how to call c# method in JS.

Comment: Thanks for help, I don't have full control on the html content based video tag. Is there a way I can get signal from webview on play as pause. I see some callback things used in renderer for scrollheight. is there anything similar to that.

Comment: Is this event can be put on body, it might have multiple video on content.

Comment: You can set ID of each video and stop playing in JS.